# jQuery UI draggable returns unexpected position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag background position instead of element itself.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtYem/1/)**</kbd>

Here's my code

```
var left = 0,
    top = 0;
$('#box').draggable({ 
    start: 
    drag: function (e, ui) {
        // += as I am setting left and top = 0, so just taking the 'change'
        left += ui.position.left;
        top  += ui.position.top;  


        ui.position.left = 0;
        ui.position.top = 0;

        $(this).css({
            'background-position': left + 'px ' + top + 'px'
        });

    }, 
});
```

It drags very fast and soon the `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` reaches a big value.

I found that  `drag` event gets called twice.

Drag function gives the correct dragged position for the first time, but for the second time, I guess, it adds `background-position` values to itself.

Comment: Seems like you are adding the element's position to the background position? They are two very different things. It will certainly be very high very soon.

Comment: but I am doing `ui.position.left = 0;` at each drag. If I see the style, its always `top:0` and `left:0`

Comment: @Jaswant But right before that you are doing `left += ui.position.left;`, and then using `left` for the bg position. You could use the console of your browser to debug your code and check how your variables change as your code is executed step-by-step.

Comment: I am looking at the console. Drag event fires two times. For the first time,it gives values equal to scrolled position. But second time, it gives large values.

Comment: I've included the jsfiddle already. Let me bold that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're dragging, jQuery UI appears to keep track of the `ui.position` regardless of you setting it `0`. So, if you move it one pixel to the right, `left` is `1`. You then set it to `0`, but when you (without stopping) drag it another pixel to the right, `ui.position.left` is actually `2`, not `1`.

So here's the solution.

1. Keep track of the `ui.position` values and subtract them while dragging (thus, we calculate the difference between the previous move and the new move).
2. When dragging stops, reset these values to `0` (otherwise the background keeps jumping back to `0px 0px`).

I've updated your Fiddle, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtYem/2/ (I added those `<span>` tags for analyzing the coordinates, so you can delete them again).

Comment: Yeah, I suspected the same. Used `stop` without luck. Your solution works fine. Any quick fix to constrain image, so that it does not leave white space (i.e. only allow dragging with background image fully covering the `div`) ?

Comment: I guess you'll just need to make sure that `top` and `left` are never `> 0` (white space top and left) and never `< size of picture` (white space on the right and bottom.

Comment: Hmm...I've finally decided to use an `img` tag inside the container instead. No more `background-position`

Comment: Yeah, that's probably easier.